# How can I find the equivalent of -locationInNode for an NSTouch?

Tags: macos, cocoa-touch, sprite-kit, nsevent, nstouch

My SpriteKit Mac application responds to NSTouch events via -touchesBeganWithEvent:(NSEvent)event.  However, calling -locationInNode only gives me the location of the mouse coordinate for that NSTouch.  But what I'm trying to do is map the touch coordinate on the trackpad to the screen like so:

```
NSTouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
CGPoint sceneCoord;
sceneCoord.x = touch.normalizedPosition.x * self.size.width;
sceneCoord.y = touch.normalizedPosition.y * self.size.height;
```

That will translate the trackpad coordinate to the window / scene coordinate.  But I need to know the location of the touch in one of the SKNode's that's in the scene.  For mouse clicks I'd just use [event locationInNode:theNode], but I can't use that call since I'm manually calculating the event coordinate above.

I'm surprised that SpriteKit doesn't have any calls for dealing with NSTouches.

Comment: how did you get your scene to respond to -touchesBeganWithEvent: ?

Answer (score 1):

Since `SKScene` is a subclass of `SKNode`, you can call [`[SKNode convertPoint:toNode:]`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKNode_Ref/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013023-CH1-SW46) on your `SKScene` to convert the coordinates to your node.

```
NSTouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
CGPoint sceneCoord;
sceneCoord.x = touch.normalizedPosition.x * self.size.width;
sceneCoord.y = touch.normalizedPosition.y * self.size.height;

SKNode *nodeOfInterest = ...
CGPoint locationInNode = [scene convertPoint:sceneCoord toNode:nodeOfInterest];
```